# Fill a GridView with List Map results

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fill a GridView with results of a List Map

```
  var players = [
    {"Name": "Josh", "Age": "25"},
    {"Name": "Rick", "Age": "26"},
    {"Name": "Michael", "Age": "22"},
    {"Name": "Sander", "Age": "23"},
  ];
```

I would like to fill a GridView with the results above, but when I use List.generate the message "***The element type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.dartlist_element_type_not_assignable***
" appears for me.

The code where I try to fill the GridView

```
    GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: [
        List.generate(players.length, (index) => {
          
        })
      ],
    )
```

Is there any way to fill this GridView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do either way:

`1st: By using the .map() method:`

```
 var players = [
    {"Name": "Josh", "Age": "25"},
    {"Name": "Rick", "Age": "26"},
    {"Name": "Michael", "Age": "22"},
    {"Name": "Sander", "Age": "23"},
 ];

 GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: players.map(
      (player) => Column(children: [
        Text(player['Name']),
        Text(player['Age'])
        ])).toList()
 )
```

`2nd: By using the List.generate() method`

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: List<Widget>.generate(
      players.length,
      (index) => Column(children: [
        Text(players[index]['Name']),
        Text(players[index]['Age'])
        ])
    )
)
```

Comment: That's it! Thank You :)